# How can i know current foreground activity(not from service)?

Tags: android, service, android-activity, android-intent

I am having alert generation application. I want to start or switch to other(Third) activity from current activity(foreground) using another activity's context(middle). From current activity(foreground) i m switching to other(middle) activity using intents and from this switched activity again i m switching to another(third) activity using intents. Due to such scenario, i am getting little but flash of middle activity in between current foreground activity and final most(third) activity. 
How can i resolve this one?

For this purpose i want to know current foreground activity or is there any other solution?

I am not having any ideas about this one. Highly appreciate solutions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Current activity context can be obtained in the following simple way.

```
            Context currentContext=this;
```

hope it solves your question.

Comment: Can i hide the middle activity view while switching from foreground activity view to third activity view because i m using intents? 
Due to use of intents for switching activities i get flashing of middle activity's view which i don't want.